# Collision detection between specific bodies in Cocos2D-x and Box2d

Tags: xcode5, box2d, cocos2d-x, collision-detection

i want to know how to configure the `b2contactlistener` in right way. i learned many tutorials , but they not helped me very well. At last i detected the collision generally. but not for specific bodies. so kindly guide me how detect collision for specific bodies.while i am using `cocos2d-x 2.1.5` and `box2d`. here is code which i used.

```
class MyListener : public b2ContactListener
{
   void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{

    b2Fixture* fixtureA = contact->GetFixtureA();
    b2Fixture* fixtureB = contact->GetFixtureB();
    b2Body* body1 = fixtureA->GetBody();
    b2Body* body2 = fixtureB->GetBody();
    cout << "started";


   }
void MyListener::EndContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
    cout << "ended\n";
}


};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check out `b2body->setUserData()`. You can store there anything you want to determine which body is which object, for example if you have many objects of the same class, say ball and an object of needle then you could store in the userdata of ball object a pointer to the actual ball sprite which has a Tag = 1 and in the needle obj a sprite with tag = 2. Then in your method perform a check `if((body1->getUserData())->getTag() == 1) ...` and you know everything

Comment: In class MyListener where i using BeginContact(),i can't access the bodies from  other class HelloWorld where i declares my bodies and sprites. i also try to use this BeginContact(b2Contact contact ) in Helloworld::update. but there was no responce. if you can you provide me whole cod or link where i easily understand. Thanks for fast reply..

Comment: Well of course you can access them. [This](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-callbacks) is a very good website with tutorials and source code

Comment: You can give the MyListener class a reference to the HelloWorld class, or make it a global variable etc.

Comment: @iforce2d yesterday  i also refrenced the Mlistener class to HelloWorld class.                                             In HelloWorld.h  'Class HelloWorld : Public cocos2d::CClayer     { private: MyLister Listner; }'. after that in HelloWorld.cpp, In constructor:  void HelloWorld::HelloWorld { world->SetContactListener(&listener); }. In update method: void  update(float dt) { listener.contacts.BeginContact(b2Contact *contact)   } .. So how i use Listener in my Update method? in update method what should be in place of (b2Contact * contact)??

Comment: I would not use the listener in the update method... "listener" means that it listens for events, you don't call it yourself. When the listener gets an event, it can call a function in the HelloWorld class.

Comment: @iforce2d i detected the bodies which are collided with each other. but my game crash sometimes due to one of these two threads. which are following                                                                
Thread No.1:-
void CCObject::retain(void)
{
    CCAssert(m_uReference > 0, "reference count should greater than 0");

    ++m_uReference;
}

Thread No.2:-
inline bool b2World::IsLocked() const
{
    return (m_flags & e_locked) == e_locked;
}

Comment: I detected the collisions between bodies by getting the tags of sprites in Listener method. Thanks to all :)